# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of nullopenRequest.onupgradeneeded Indexeddb

Tags: cordova

I encounter the above when trying to open two objects in IndexDB and  get data from the Input value.Please can anyone tell me where am wrong , here is the code

```
 openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {         

    var thisDB = e.target.result;

  var tab1Create = thisDB.createObjectStore("users", {keyPath: "phone"});

var tab2Create = thisDB.createObjectStore("Friends", {keyPath: "frdphone"});

    db = e.target.result;

var transaction = e.target.transaction;
var phone = document.querySelector("#phone").value;         
var email = document.querySelector("#email").value;
var frdphone = document.querySelector("#frdphone").value;

var frdname = document.querySelector('#frdname').value;     

 var friend = transaction.objectStore('Friends');
friend.add({
 frdname:frdname,
 frdphone:frdphone
 });
var user = transaction.objectStore('users');
 //Perform the add
 user.add({
   phone :phone,
   email :email
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

One of the accesses to property 'value' (`something.value` in code) is failing because `something` is null. The only places where `.value` is used are `document.querySelector()` calls. So one of those is returning no result, i.e. null.

This has nothing to do with Indexed DB - you're using a selector that is not matching any elements in your document.

Comment: Thank you, Joshua, for fixing the null value i get the error    " Uncaught DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': An object could not be cloned."    please what could be the problem?

Comment: It's hard to tell without more context. That indicates (as it says) that the object passed to `.add()` could not be cloned. In the code sample given it looks like you'd be passing objects containing strings, which should be fine.

Comment: A guess: Did you change `var phone = document.querySelector("#phone").value; ` to `var phone = document.querySelector("#phone");` ? That would mean `phone` is referencing an element, and elements can't be cloned. I would suggest you try doing `console.log(...)` or try other debugging approaches to understand why the code is not doing what you expect.

Comment: Thanks will try that too.